# Insert Join with limit - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How do I go about doing an update with a join while using a limit

Error - Illegal use of limit operator

```
UPDATE  
     table1  
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id  
SET  
     table1.field = 'your_value'
WHERE  
     table1.id = table2.id  
LIMIT 1500
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution, it's a bit of a hack

```
SET @tmp_c = 0;
UPDATE
    table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.id = table3.id
SET
    table1.remove_date = NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH
WHERE
    table1.active = 1
AND
    (IF (table1.active = 1, @tmp_c := @tmp_c + 1 , 0 )) //This is to only increment the counter if the whole where matches
AND
    @tmp_c <= 15 //Start ignoring row items as soon as it exceeds the limit amount
```

;

Comment: The implizite join parts in where are unnesessary because you have thse in the explizite join ( table1.id = table2.id
)

Comment: Ya that's true.

It mostly comes from being paranoid :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want limit you should use a subselect and join this

```
UPDATE  table1  
INNER JOIN ( select * from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id  
LIMIT 1500 ) t on t.id = table1.id
SET  table1.field = 'your_value'
```